# mongo - why my $sum:1 not counting?

Tags: python, mongodb

I follow the [official guide here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/aggregation-with-user-preference-data/) to code my sandbox as [data intial here](https://github.com/namgivu/mongo-start/blob/master/query-tutorial.python/02_aggregate_seeding.py), and the [query code here](https://github.com/namgivu/mongo-start/blob/master/query-tutorial.python/03a_aggr_query.py)

They query in python

```
p=[{ "$project": { "month_joined": {"$month": "$joined"}  }},
   { "$group":   { "_id": {"month_joined": "$month_joined", "qty": {"$sum": 1}}  }},
   { "$sort":    { "_id.month_joined": 1  }},
   ]; qc=db.users.aggregate(p); mongo_print(qc)

p=[{ "$project": { "yyyy": {"$year": "$joined"}  }},
   { "$group":   { "_id": {"yyyy": "$yyyy", "qty": {"$sum": 1}}  }},
   { "$sort":    { "_id.yyyy": 1  }},
   ]; qc=db.users.aggregate(p); mongo_print(qc)
```

And I always get the counting result as 1

```
{'_id': {'month_joined': 1, 'qty': 1}}
{'_id': {'month_joined': 4, 'qty': 1}}
{'_id': {'month_joined': 6, 'qty': 1}}

{'_id': {'yyyy': 2011, 'qty': 1}}
{'_id': {'yyyy': 2012, 'qty': 1}}
{'_id': {'yyyy': 2016, 'qty': 1}}
```

What I've done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the closing brace in the `group` stage placed wrong. The `_id` should contain only month and year, respectively. It should read like this:

```
p=[{ "$project": { "month_joined": {"$month": "$joined"}  }},
   { "$group":   { "_id": {"month_joined": "$month_joined"}, "qty": {"$sum": 1}  }},
   { "$sort":    { "_id.month_joined": 1  }},
   ]; qc=db.users.aggregate(p); mongo_print(qc)

p=[{ "$project": { "yyyy": {"$year": "$joined"}  }},
   { "$group":   { "_id": {"yyyy": "$yyyy"}, "qty": {"$sum": 1}  }},
   { "$sort":    { "_id.yyyy": 1  }},
   ]; qc=db.users.aggregate(p); mongo_print(qc)
```